# Not display page with meta - front.tpl.php

Tags: 7, meta-tags

When I use metatags and page--front.tpl.php, the meta will not be displayed. But when I remove the top page--front.tpl.php, meta displayed correctly.

Page =>

```
        <?php include_once 'templates/header.tpl.php'; ?>

        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <div id="gbl-content">
            <div id="content-maison">
                <?php print render($page['content']);?>
            </div>
                            <div id="sidebar-right-custom">
                    <div>
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($node)) :
                                if($node->nid == 57 || $node->title == 'Le label BBC') :
                                    foreach ($node->field_imagead['fr'] as $key => $imgMaison) :
                                        echo '<img src="'.$base_path.path_to_theme().'/images/bbc.png" class="bbc" title="&Eacute;ligible BBC" style="margin: -7px 0 0 249px" />';
                                        echo '<img src="'.file_create_url($imgMaison['uri']).'" id="thumbnail_'.$key.'" class="imgBBC" />';
                                    endforeach;
                        ?>
                            <div class="textCadreBBC">
                                Maison Atlantique Demeures<br/>
                                bénéficiant du label BBC
                            </div>
                        <?php 
                                endif;
                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                        if(isset($node)) :
                            $nid = $node->nid;
                            $daily = get_dailymotion($nid);
                        foreach ($daily['query'] as $key => $value) :
                    ?>
                    <div id="dailymotion-bcc">
                        <span class="dailyTitle"><?php echo $value['title'] ?></span>
                        <iframe frameborder="0" width="260" height="194" src="<?php echo $value['video'] ?>?width=260"></iframe>
                        <div class="daily_allvideos">
                            <a style="font-size: 13px; color: #666666;" title="Voir toutes les vidéos" href="#" target="_blank">Voir toutes les vidéos</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                        endforeach;
                        endif; 
                    ?>
                    <?php include 'templates/sidebar-info.php';?>
                </div>

                    <div class="clearer"></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <?php include 'templates/footer.tpl.php';?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Front =>

```
        <?php include_once 'header.tpl.php'; ?>

        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <div id="gbl-content">
            <?php  include_once path_to_theme().'/carrousel.tpl.php'  ?>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="content-text">
                    <h2><span class="title_bleu">Bienvenue chez</span> <span class="title_orange">Atlantique Demeures</span></h2>
                    <p class="text"><span class="textOrange">ATLANTIQUE DEMEURES</span>, constructeur de maisons individuelles en Loire Atlantique (44) vous accompagne tout au long de la construction de votre projet : maison plain pied, à étage, maison en Z, BBC, terrain…</p>
                    <div class="separatorText"></div>
                    <p class="text paddingLeft10">
                        Bénéficiez des garanties <span class="textOrange">ATLANTIQUE DEMEURES</span>: garantie décennale-biennale, garantie de <br/>dommage-ouvrage, garantie de remboursement
                        de l’acompte, garantie à prix et délais convenus.
                    </p>
                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    <div id="blocTerrain">
                        <div class="bc-haut"><a href="/terrains">Terrains à bâtir</a></div>
                        <div class="bc-bas">
                            <a href="/terrains"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $base_path.path_to_theme().'/images/maison.jpg' ?>"></a>
                            <p><a href="/terrains">Trouvez votre terrain dans le secteur de votre choix pour la construction de votre maison.</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="blocMaison">
                        <div class="bc-haut"><a href="/maisons">Maisons</a></div>
                        <div class="bc-bas">
                            <a href="/maisons"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $base_path.path_to_theme().'/images/maison.jpg' ?>"></a>
                            <p><a href="/maisons">Choisissez une maison correspondant à vos besoins parmi nos différentes gammes.</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="blocExclu">
                        <div class="bc-haut"><a href="/exclus">Nos exclusivités</a></div>
                        <div class="bc-bas">
                            <a href="/exclus"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $base_path.path_to_theme().'/images/maison.jpg' ?>"></a>
                            <p><a href="/exclus">Découvrez tous nos packs maison + terrain pour la construction de votre projet.</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="blocBBC">
                        <div class="bc-haut"><a href="/maisons-bbc">Maisons BBC</a></div>
                        <div class="bc-bas">
                            <a href="/maisons-bbc"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $base_path.path_to_theme().'/images/maison.jpg' ?>"></a>
                            <p><a href="/maisons-bbc">Réalisez des économies d'énergie en construisant une maison BBC</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php 
                     $query = db_select('dailymotion', 'd');
                     $query->fields('d');
                     $query->join('dailymotion_node', 'dn' , 'd.did = dn.did');
                     $query->condition('dn.nid', 0);
                     $result2 = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
                ?>
                <div id="sidebar-right">
                    <span class="dailyDecouverte">Découvrez virtuellement visite en vidéo de la</span>
                    <span class="dailyTitle"><?php echo $result2->title ?></span>
                    <iframe frameborder="0" width="260" height="194" src="<?php echo $result2->video ?>?width=260"></iframe>
                    <div class="daily_allvideos">
                        <a style="font-size: 13px; color: #666666;" title="Voir toutes les vidéos" href="#" target="_blank">Voir toutes les vidéos</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
            </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <?php include 'footer.tpl.php';?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like page.tpl.php prints a certain variable, but page--front.tpl.php does not. However it's hard to tell because I can't see your code. If this isn't enough help for you, please update your question and post the code from your page and page--front tpl files.

[update]

I believe @akalata is right about html.tpl.php, but that said: You're clearly hacking your way around the Drupal theme system, instead of using is the way it's meant to be used. Your template files above are a mix of styling (html, images, inline css), functionality (db queries, menu-items) and content (caroussel, video). If that works for you, I will not stop you. However it hard for me to help you with it and IMHO, you shouldn't be surprised that some modules break.

Comment: In D7, the meta tags should print in html.tpl.php, not the page.tpl.php. My guess is that this is either a module bug or misconfiguration.

Comment: Doesn't work with a custom `html.tpl.php`. Is it possible to change the variable `$head?` . If not for my pages, I will solve the problems of inline CSS. What can I do to help: Images, queries, the carousel and videos?

Comment: Your site already uses the default html.tpl.php, so overriding that will add complexity rather than solve existing problems. Drupal theming is such a huge topic, I can't explain that in a single comment. You can start by reading some of the [documentation](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7). Some guidelines: Try to keep functionality ("how your site works") in modules and configuration. Use nodes for your content, and blocks for one-off elements such as a caroussel. Use the theme layer (templates and CSS) only at the end, when all functionality is done, to make your site look good.